# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' and Gradle stopped executing

Tags: android

I tried to run the app in Android Studio and I faced 1 error which I tried to correct but i cannot. Any help on this would be thankful.
here I am attaching my gradle code.
1st gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kpm.com.shopping"
    minSdkVersion 5
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

compile files('libs/android-9.jar')
}
```

And my second gradle code.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to   all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the error i am facing currently in my code.                        Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: try adding `multiDexEnabled true` inside defaultConfig

Answer (score 0):

Use this gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0'
```

replace `dependencies` with:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/android-9.jar')
}
```

Comment: Still it is having the same problem. but with different error message where the task is different from the previous one.                                                                                       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: try with gradle 1.4.0 or return back to 1.2.3 to solve

Answer (score 0):

Edit your gradle like this :

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Comment: it is saying gradle DSL method not found when i add this particular pice of code

Comment: Hey @PRASANTHMAMAKAR, Please make sure you have the latest Gradle and Android Studio: